# Фон блока прокручивается со страницей

Tags: html, css, parallax

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#clear_first {
  position: relative;
  background: #c8504b;
  opacity: 0.4;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#clear_second {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#clear_third {
  position: relative;
  background: #000000;
  opacity: 0.9;
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#paral {
  position: absolute;
  background: url(https://kondainfo.ru/images/delim_10.jpg) no-repeat bottom fixed;
  background-size: 100% 200px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="clear_first">Начало</div>
<div id="clear_second">
  <div id="paral">Фото параллакса</div>
</div>
<div id="clear_third">Конец</div>
```

Здравствуйте всем! Помогите пожалуйста зафиксировать фон блока div, чтоб он смог останавливаться, а не проваливаться в бездну вместе с ползунком. Решил добавить на свой сайт (я ещё совсем новичок) простой как табурет эффект параллакса. Код обрезал.

```
jsfiddle.net/acsoncry/655zna8L
```

Проблема заключается в том, что изображение в высоту всего 200 пикселей, а сам блок в два раза тоньше. Когда прокручиваешь страницу вниз, в какой - то момент картинка параллакса прокручивается и изображение исчезает, оставляя пустую область. Перепробовал множество способов создания параллаксов, включая остановку блока при достижении другого (сам ступил, блок же на месте стоит, двигается только картинка...), но там рассматриваются крупногабаритные фото, заменяющие друг друга. В моём же случае блок узкий и картинка как бы "прыгает" там, но дна у блока нет. Возможно каким-либо способом ограничить высоту самого блока? Пробовал сделать background-size: 100% 100%;, но тогда картинку растягивает на высоту экрана... Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: не помню сколько раз перечитал, так и не поня, что где должно остановиться...

Comment: Михаил Астахов, учти на будущее, если хочешь получить помощь, оформляй вопрос правильно...

Comment: как смог так и оформил

Comment: на сайте, есть определенные правила...  будет полезно почитать  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял в вашем случае вам поможет `background-size: cover;`. Но кроме того я бы немного уменьшил бы картинку, что бы его ширина примерно было ровно ширине вашего блока, только потом поставил бы его в фоне. Что бы все части картинки нормально были видны.

```css
html, body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  }
  
  #clear_first{
  position:relative;
  background:#c8504b;
  opacity:0.4;
  height:300px;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  }
  
#clear_second {
  position:relative;
  background:#ccc;
  opacity:1;
  height:700px;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  }
  
#clear_third {
  position:relative;
  background:#000000;
  opacity:0.9;
  height:700px;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  }
  
#paral {
   position: absolute;
   background: url(https://kondainfo.ru/images/delim_10.jpg) no-repeat bottom fixed;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: left center;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;    
   border-top: 1px solid;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="clear_first">Начало</div>
  <div id="clear_second">
    <div id="paral">Фото параллакса</div>
  </div>
  <div id="clear_third">Конец</div>
</body>
```

Comment: ах вот о чем он....)))))

Comment: @Air Код в примере `jsfiddle` выдает именно ту ошибку о чем говорил автор.

Comment: блин, придётся наверное всё - таки параллакс с js настраивать... при ковере картинка не растягивается, а просто увеличивается до гигантских размеров :)

Comment: @МихаилАстахов посмотрите что делает ковер, и еще я там писал что делать с размерами изоброжения

Comment: я понял, спасибо :) у меня на странице просто много тонких и широких полосок, поэтому ковер их деформирует. поэтому тут только вот фиксировать его и замедлять скорость прокручивания элемента... в любом случае спасибо за помощь!